# Tesseract OCR cube files for Turkish

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Where can I find tesseract ocr Turkish language extension for [cube](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr-extradocs/wiki/Cube) mode ?

files:

```
tr.cube.fold
tr.cube.lm
tr.cube.nn
tr.cube.params
tr.cube.size
tr.cube.word-freq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere. Cube is dead-end and will be eliminated from tesseract e.g. see https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/40

Answer (score 6):

It includes all files, just this file is enough *"tur.traineddata"*

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/tur.traineddata

and

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/tree/master/tur

--

You could also use the trained data from [tessdata_fast](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast) if you really need performance and are willing to lose some accuracy.

Grab the Turkish version at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast/blob/master/tur.traineddata